# Lambda timeout after 6s even after increasing timeout period

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I am running a scheduled lambda that runs every 24 hours and I am using Serverless to configure it. Initially I did not have any timeouts configured in the scheduled functions so when the lambda would run every 24 hours I would get the following error message:

> Task timed out after 6.01 seconds

My lambda would also fire another 2 times after that (within seconds apart) as lambdas by default will retry twice if they fail.

To resolve this issue I updated my serverless.yml file to this:

```
service: my-service
configValidationMode: error
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    STAGE: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
        - lambda:InvokeAsync
      Resource: "*"
functions:
  first_message_reminder:
    timeout: 29
    maximumRetryAttempts: 0
    handler: handler.messageReminder
    environment:
      reminderAfterDays: 3
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(24 hours)
          enabled: true

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-offline-schedule
```

As you can see I have the timeout set to 29 (29 seconds) and the maximumRetryAttempts set to 0 (in case it fails).

After looking in the AWS console it looks like the lambda has deployed properly from Serverless and I can see that the timeout is set to:

Timeout
0min29sec

I am however still getting the same timeout error after 6s when my lambda runs, why is this?

Comment: You are invoking your function asynchroniously? What does this function do?

Comment: yes it is an async function. It checks a db for unread messages and then sends email reminders using another lambda. I would hav ethough the content of it should be irrelevant as it is still timing out at 6s when it should be at 29s...

Comment: Is your lambda inside VPC?

Comment: No it's is not..